# Do I need a transit visa at London Heathrow to travel to Leeds from India?

Tags: transit

I need to travel  to Leeds from India and the flight itinerary will be
India to Doha to London Heathrow to Leeds.

The travel website tells me a transit visa may be needed for this trip. The layover time is more than 13 hours and it's the next day, ie I arrive at Heathrow on the 6th evening and my flight to Leeds will be on the 7th morning.

I hold an Indian passport and a valid work permit to work in the UK. Do I need a transit visa for the above itinerary if the layover time is long or the connection flight is on the next day?

I believe transit visas are not needed for domestic transfers, but the ticketing website says a transit visa is required. Can any one confirm please?

Comment: The ticketing website does not say a transit visa is required. It says a transit visa *may* be required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No No No**. You already have a visa for the whole of the U.K. Why would you need one to transit from one of its cities to another?

What that website says is a generic statement to encompass a number of cases. That notice does not apply to you.

> ie i arrive at heathrow on 6th evening and my flight to leeds will be on 7th morning.

Heathrow shuts down at night, you will clear immigration there and you will have to arrange somewhere to sleep overnight. If you are granted entry you will already be in the UK before your flight to Leeds.

Comment: thanks , that really make sense...but the travel agencies are putting informations that are scary :)